# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta que devuelva un registro con la fecha mas reciente?

Tags: mysql

Quiero realizar la siguiente consulta: 
Tengo una tabla con los pagos y fechas correspondientes.

```
+---------+---------------------+--------------

| Pago_Id | Fecha_Pago          | idVehiculo | 

+---------+---------------------+--------------

|       1 | 2016-07-01 18:27:37 | 98          |

|       2 | 2016-07-01 18:44:17 | 10          |

|       4 | 2016-07-01 20:00:17 | 10          |

+---------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando consulte los datos me retorne el registro con la última fecha. El problema es que cuando hago la consulta para el vehículo con id 98 no lo hace por que toma en cuenta la última fecha de la tabla y yo lo quiero hacer para la última fecha por registro. Esta es mi consulta:

```
 SELECT
         Fecha_Pago
    FROM
        gps_pagos_tbl
    WHERE
        gps_pagos_tbl.Num_Economico = '98'

    AND
        Fecha_Pago=(select max(Fecha_Pago)from gps_pagos_tbl) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en tu condición del `WHERE` está haciendo justo lo que le estas pidiendo. devolverte los registros que cumplan con ambas condiciones que se el `Num_Economico` `'98'` y que sea el mayor de `Fecha_Pago` de la tabla `gps_pagos_tbl`. Como no hay ningun registro que cumpla ambas condiciones la consulta no devuelve nada.

Además como solo necesitas un registro puedes restringirlo con `LIMIT 1`

Intenta esta consulta en su lugar. El truco es devolver todas los registros con el `idVehiculo` `'98'` y ordenarlos por `Fecha_Pago` de forma descendente, así el primer registro será el que tenga mayor fecha. Luego solo basta con tomar el primero.

```
SELECT
    Fecha_Pago
FROM
    gps_pagos_tbl
WHERE
    gps_pagos_tbl.idVehiculo = '98'
ORDER BY
    Fecha_Pago DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: En Mysql se debe usar [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) en lugar de `TOP`.

Comment: Gracias, ya está corregido

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!! Lo he implementado  y funciono!!